# Making Vim work with Unicode: what is the reason to use "setglobal fileencoding=utf-8"?

Tags: vimrc, encoding

[There is a tip on Vim Wiki](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Working_with_Unicode) about working with Unicode:

```
if has("multi_byte")
  if &encoding !~? '^u'
    if &termencoding == ""
      let &termencoding = &encoding
    endif
    set encoding=utf-8
  endif
  setglobal fileencoding=utf-8
  set fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,latin1
endif
```

I spent a lot of time trying to understand the purpose of using `setglobal fileencoding=utf-8` line and I still don't understand.

- What is the possible purpose of specifying `fileencoding` here at all? (Why not leave it to be "inherited" from `encoding` for new buffers and from `fileencodings` when we open an existing file?)
- And why `setglobal` instead of `set`?

Comment: what exactly are you missing from my answer?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Nothing special, Christian. I just want to draw more attention because this snippet interests me for quite a long period of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the recommendation for setting fileencoding instead of having it inherit from the encoding setting, is more or less to have it explicit that you are preferring UTF-8. In addition, since this is a buffer-local option, you don't want to set this only for the currently edited buffer (which ever that may be at the time of reading your .vimrc initialization file) but to have it globally apply, therefore using `setg` instead of `set`.

And finally, it is recommended to not mess with the value of `encoding` option after it has been initially set, because this may invalidate all the currently stored information your Vim is currently using (that may be register values, variables and possibly even buffer content).

Comment: *"Since this is a buffer-local option, you don't want to set this only for the currently edited buffer **(which ever that may be at the time of reading your .vimrc initialization file)**"* - Hello, Christian. Could you provide a step-by-step case that will show the exact problem? I don't mean you're wrong, I simply don't understand.